# How to find xpath element partially using selenium with java?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to select partially an element with xpath in my selenium code.

My xpath is

```
//iron-pages[@id='pages']//span[.='s8718216']
```

what I want is to select any element starting with s, the element just after span.

I tried this:

```
//iron-pages[starts-with(span[.='s'])
```

It doesn't work for me.

Can someone help me.

Comment: You mean any element with `text` starting with `s`?

Comment: Yes Rafal, because it displays a list of element starting with s

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this xpath should work `//iron-pages[starts-with(text(),'s')]`

Or second try:

`//iron-pages[starts-with(.,'s')]` <- `.` instead of `text()` checks element for more properties. Not only text.

There are many properties that might contain text like `innerText`, `innerHTML` etc.

EDIT:
I just read your question again. You want to select element right after `span` so:

`//iron-pages[@id='pages']//span[starts-with(text(),'s')]` <- it will select `span` elements starting with text `s`.

If you want child elements you can use

`//iron-pages[@id='pages']//span//*[starts-with(text(),'s')]`

Comment: Thank you Rafael, this solution //iron-pages[@id='pages']//span[starts-with(text(),'s')] works for me.

Comment: @kirkdouglas Glad I could help :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Your xpath should be

```
//iron-pages[starts-with(span[.='s'])//following-sibling::i[1]
```

it will get the next element that start with span with text s